# JavaScript, остановить выполнение функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

После данного кода останавливается сам `each`, но код после (пример - `alert('abc');`) выполняется.
Как остановить всю функцию, при отрицательном условии внутри `each`?

```js
function A() {
  $('input').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) return false;
  });

  alert('abc');
}
```

Comment: все было бы проще, если бы в js был нормальный `goto` :-D

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте дополнительную переменную для этого

```
function A() {
  let error = false;
  $('input').each(() => {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
       error = true;
       return false;
    }
  });
  if(error) return false;
  alert('success');
}
```

Comment: Это усложнит функцию. Нет ли способа как в php break?

Comment: @Gleb, нет, в данном случае, с использованием метода `each` нельзя

Comment: @Gleb поменяйте each на обычный цикл for да и всё)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  if (!Array.prototype.every.call($('input'), function (input) {return $(input).val()})) {
    return;
  }

  alert('abc');
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input> <button>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите коротко то так. Работает.

```
function A() {
  $('input').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) throw new Error("Выход из функции!");
  });

  alert('abc');
}
```